# Kivy error with text input

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to run this code in my pc, i tried every ways to do it but always I get the same error, I don't know what to do...

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7') 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.codeinput import CodeInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)


class Myapp(App):

    def build(self):

        self.layout = BoxLayout(padding=50,orientation="vertical",spacing=30)
        Labe_Prin = Label(text="Bienvenido al login",font_name="data/fonts/Union_soap.ttf",color=(0,0,0,0.5),font_size=50)
        Label1 = Label(text="Ingrese Usuario: ",color=(0,0,0,1),font_size=(50*0.75),bold=True,italic=False,font_name="data/fonts/English_.ttf")
        Entrada1 = TextInput(multiline = False,size_hint=(1,.3),bold=True,font_size=12.3,foreground_color=(.5,.1,.3,1),text="Usuraio",use_bubble=True) #focus=True,use_handles=True
        Label2 = Label(text="Ingrese Contrasenia: ",color=(0,0,0,1),font_size=(50*0.75),bold=True,italic=False,font_name="data/fonts/English_.ttf")
        Entrada2 = CodeInput(multiline = False,size_hint=(1,.3),italic=True,font_size=12.3,foreground_color=(.5,.1,.3,1),text="Contrasenia",use_buble=True) #Contrasenia

        def press(self):
            print Entrada1.text
            print Entrada2.text

        Boton1 = Button(size_hint=(1, .4), text='Login',on_release=press)


        self.layout.add_widget(Labe_Prin)
        self.layout.add_widget(Label1)
        self.layout.add_widget(Entrada1)
        self.layout.add_widget(Label2)
        self.layout.add_widget(Entrada2)
        self.layout.add_widget(Boton1)

        return self.layout

if __name__=="__main__":
    Myapp().run()
```

and i have this error...

```
[CRITICAL          ] [Cutbuffer   ] Unable to find any valuable Cutbuffer provider at all!
xclip - OSError: [Errno 2] No existe el archivo o el directorio
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/clipboard/clipboard_xclip.py", line 17, in <module>
p = subprocess.Popen(['xclip', '-version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception

xsel - OSError: [Errno 2] No existe el archivo o el directorio
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/clipboard/clipboard_xsel.py", line 15, in <module>
p = subprocess.Popen(['xsel'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
```

I can execute the code, but i can't build to android

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got same error, but installing xclip & xsel fixed this for me.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04: "sudo apt update"
"sudo apt upgrade"
"sudo apt install xclip xsel"

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get install xclip xsel
```

Comment: Isn't this the same advice as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34516867/7404943)?

Answer (score 2):

I got same error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install xclip xsel
```

But it didn't help because some Ubuntu based OS (like *Xubuntu 20.04.1 focal*) haven't available needed packages. In this case (when you've got "E: Unable to locate package xclip") you need to add repository with this packages:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt-get install xclip xsel
```

*P.S. Maybe you'll need just **universe** or **multiverse repository** , but I install both of them.*

*P.S.S. It's just detailed answer of the question. Cause I took about 30 minutes to find solution for error with "Unable to locate package * ".*